# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function Dotenv\Dotenv()

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am trying to build a website to practice a code where. I am finding a strange error

[image: errpr]

Which I am unable to replicate how to solve the issue.

I have followed the steps.

I already downloaded the Vendor by Composer and here is the code I have used. Then I installed last pacjage.

> composer require vlucas/phpdotenv

[image: folders]

.env

```
APP_URL=http://oxbir.me
APP_ENV=local
APP_NAME="ACSE E-Commerce Store"
```

index.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../bootstrap/init.php';
$app_name = getenv('APP_NAME');
echo $app_name;
```

init.php

```
<?php
require_once __DIR__.'/../app/config/_env.php';
```

_env.php

```
<?php
define('BASE_PATH', realpath(__DIR__.'/../../'));
require_once __DIR__.'/../../vendor/autoload.php';
$dotEnv = Dotenv\Dotenv(BASE_PATH);
$dotEnv->load();
```

Comment: Have you checked the documentation `$dotenv = Dotenv\Dotenv::createImmutable(__DIR__);`

Comment: I get this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcIRj.png

Comment: The error is listing the files it is trying to read and can't find any, so did you replace `__DIR__` with `BASE_PATH` from your code.

Comment: It is not show error. but I have a problem. I want to show `APP_NAME` in index page